# Download a file from command line in laravel artisan

Tags: php, laravel, file, zip

I am using laravel Artisan Commands to download a file from public folder .

Actually i want to download a zip file which i have successfully made in public folder.

I am able to download the file when I call the methods on button click.

But when I execute the command in console it does not work and also not throw any error.

```
public function downloadExportRawData() {
    $a=public_path().'/temp/rawexport/rawexportproduct.zip';
    $path='/temp/rawexport/rawexportproduct.zip';
    if(file_exists('temp/rawexport/rawexportproduct.zip')){
        return Response::download($a);
    }else{
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Tried this also...

```
public static function downloadZip($rand_folder, $zipname, $fileName) {

    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '.zip"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));

    $handle = fopen($zipname, 'rb');
    //exec("rm -r ".$temp);
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        echo fread($handle, 1048576);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
   // exec("rm -r " . $rand_folder);
}
```

and the command is

```
php artisan product:export --from=http://localhost/valuable-app/dev-master/rest_app/public/ --productid=5b273b0e4bb5995b108b4576 --tokenexport=354c3ddb2bd45aa6e5c4f749749b0b58cbacef48
```

The main problem is that it is going through the function in controller but not downloading it. 
And I tried to echo the response it prints code in zip form means a encoded form which have something related to my zip file means its printing the zip not downloading it. 
I am using Artisan first time. Any idea how to download that file using using user-defined Artisan command.

I am trying this from last two weeks but not able to do anything.

Comment: Where are you downloading to? I suppose you want to save the file into another location since you're running it in the console.

Comment: yes in local system like in download folder

Comment: Perhaps you should look at this [article](https://laravel-news.com/custom-artisan-commands). It's a nice walkthrough writing custom artisan commands.

Comment: You have shown us your Controller code, which is set up to do *browser* downloads - setting content headers (relevant only in a browser), reading a file from local disk (only relevant to code running on the remote server), etc.  You are asking us about an artisan console command, which is something completely different, but you haven't shown us any of that code.  Where is your console code?  And remember, re-using the Controller code you've shown us won't work from the console, as I've described.

Comment: What I am doing is...
exporting the data in json format and put them into one file....
then i put this file to a /temp folder in public folder in zip format...
and then trying to download that zip file....
and after downloading deleteing that /temp folder

Comment: controller code is to make a zip file in public folder and I want to download that file by Artisan

Comment: It's pretty simple now ...I have a zip file in public folder and simply need to download it through artisan Any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

First identify the file which you want to download and then call

```
string shell_exec ( string $cmd )
```

you can use wget to get the file.

for example, in your command

```
    $fileName = $this->argument('filename');
    $file = url('storage/public/' . $fileName);
    shell_exec("wget $file");
    $this->info('downloading');
```

Comment: but it's not downloading. I dont know why. When I am using commands directoly on terminal, it's downloading but when using shell_exec its not

Comment: wget -P /home/gten/Downloads/ "http://localhost/valuable-app/dev-master/rest_app/public/temp/rawexport/rawexportproduct.zip"

Comment: i think we can do it just need little more explanation

Comment: you are close to it

Comment: --2018-07-31 11:22:08--  http://localhost/valuable-app/dev-master/rest_app/public/temp/rawexport/rawexportproduct.zip
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 26775 (26K) [application/zip]
/home/gten/Downloads/rawexportproduct.zip: Permission denied

Cannot write to '/home/gten/Downloads/rawexportproduct.zip' (Success).

Comment: it's downloading the file but in the localhost folder means in my app folder not in download folder

Comment: waiting for some more help

Answer (score 1):

if you'r using the console, the http download will not work (you are not using a browser).

Instead you can move the file to your wished destination or something like that, but not download it via console

Comment: yes i have seen it. but how will I move that file and then after downloading i have to delete that file also from server directory

Comment: its php artisan command that will download the file from server also

Answer (score 1):

console will not handle http response as download (will not save it)
I think you should consider to add second argument in your console:
`--destination=/home/user/downloads/filetosaveas.extension` and in your code use curl to download

or more simple use core curl:

```
curl http://example.com --output my.file --silent
```

Comment: can you please explain more

Comment: first I thought you want to copy file over http your local drive but in the case presented its just copy file from one folder to another isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you actually went through the nicely done **Writing Commands** guide at the Laravel Docs site, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#writing-commands).

---

In a nutshell, there are mainly two ways to register artisan command. Be it that one is an alternative to the other.

1. **(Like routes)** specify your instructions within a closure.
2. **(Like controllers)** create a command class and specify your instructions.

### The closure way

Inside my `routes/console.php`, I specify something like below:

```
Artisan::command('download:file', function () {
    // your code goes here.
})->describe('Download a file.');
```

Now execute a help routine for your newly created command.

```
-> php artisan help download:file

Description:
  Donwload a file.

Usage:
    donwload:file

//...
```

### The command way

Generate the command class using `php artisan make:command EmailFileCommand`. This command will create `app/Console/Commands/EmailFileCommand.php`. Update the file to specify what we want it to do.

```
// ...
class EmailFileCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'email:file';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Email a file.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // your code goes here.
    }
}
```

### Trigger commands via HTTP

Say you want to call the commands via an http request. In my `routes/web.php` file,

```
//...
use Artisan;

//...

Route::get('/download', function () {
    Artisan::call('download:file');
});

Route::get('/email', function () {
    Artisan::call('email:file');
});

//...
```

Now execute your http requests `/download` and `/email`.

---

To download a file, you can use Laravel's [Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem).

```
//...
use Storage;

//...

Storage::download('file.jpg')
```

---

This post has been extracted from my blog post [here](https://github.com/joshuamabina/blog/issues/8).

Comment: I have successfully made and register the command and its executing all the code but not downloading .

Comment: I have tried the FileSystem sir. It's downloading via php script like controllers but not from Artisan.

Comment: @AdeshKumar The `Storage` API retrieves files in the `~/your-app/storage/` directory. You need to make sure the file you are downloading is present in the appropriate directory. The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration) clearly explains this.

Comment: Maybe, why do you need an artisan command to download a file? Maybe there is a better way to achieve what you really want.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to figure out how you will copy/move the desired file from the desired location to a destined location.

Comment: I need to export a document in the form of zip from artisan command

Comment: if you think there is another method please tell me. i have never used it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176856/discussion-between-joshuamabina-and-adesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

One can use the shell_exec() command to run a terminal command through PHP function or script. It will execute the command without opening the terminal window. the behaviour of command will be little bit different from the original command.